# nested if python executed in one case but not in another similar condition

Tags: python, if-statement

Hi please find my code below:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    #char: a single character
    #aStr: an alphabetized string
    #returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    length=len(aStr)
    print(length, aStr)     #check
    if length == 0:
        return False
    elif length == 1:
        if char == aStr:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif char==aStr[int(length/2)]:
        return True
    elif char<aStr[int(length/2)]:
        print("checked")
        aStr=aStr[0:int(length/2)]
        isIn(char,aStr)
    elif char>aStr[int(length/2)]:
        isIn(char,aStr[int(length/2):-1])
```

if i run with

```
a='b'
s='b'
v=isIn(a,s)
print(v)
```

prints out True at the last line

if i run with

```
a='b'
s='bcd'
v=isIn(a,s)
print(v)
```

prints out None when it should print True. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to add `return` for recursive call like this `return isIn(char,aStr)`

Comment: Why this function? why not one-line built-in `'b' in 'bcd'`?

Comment: I'd like to point out that `isIn(char,aStr[int(length/2):-1])` leaves out the last element of the array: `'abcdef'[0:-1] == 'abcde'`. Probably wasn't intended that way. You probably meant `isIn(char,aStr[int(length/2):])`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write a lot of code, you can just do:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    return char in aStr
```

the 'in' keyword will return True if char is in aStr and False otherwise

Comment: unless they want to write an algorithm for education purposes in which case this is not what they are looking for, and it probably could be done using `for` loops (which is way easier than recursion) but maybe they want to also learn recursion, besides what is the point of such function anyways, just use `char in string`, you don't need to define a whole function